# Loop doesn't work without alert() in ajax readystate()

Tags: php, ajax, variables, local

Problem description:
Hello!

My XMLHTTPRequest object, when ready, does a couple of things. The responseText which I receive is split up, and sent as a parameter to `myFunction()`.

Now, I need to call `myFunction()` 'n' number of times, with substrings of the response text as parameters.

***This Works:***

```
myAjaxObj.onreadystatechange=function() 
    {   
        if(myAjaxObj.readyState==4) 
        {
            if(myAjaxObj.status==200) 
                        {
                            myFunction( myAjaxObj.responseText, id )
```

***This DOESN'T Work:***

```
myAjaxObj.onreadystatechange=function() 
    {   
        if(myAjaxObj.readyState==4) 
        {
            if(myAjaxObj.status==200) 
                        {
                            var count i=0;
                            for( i=0; i < 5; i++ )
                            {   
                                [b]alert("Without this it wont work") [/b]
                                myFunction( myAjaxObj.responseText, i );
                            }
```

Basically, the code within the for-loop won't run, unless the alert() is uncommented.
I've read somewhere about javascript closures, and the facts that it kinda gives the execution/rendering to get in sync

What would be the solution?

Comment: Can you just be sure the question says what you think it says?  The first example Works? Ok it does look sound to me.  However according the header to the second example the second example doesn't work, yet the description below the second example says that it does.  Which is it?

Comment: @Anthony:
The second ex, "works" wid the alert() enabled...
If i comment the alert, then it doesnt.
Is it some kind of sync issues, between rendering and code execution> ?

Answer (score 3):

OK, this is happening because you are not polling your onreadystatechange function. Basically, the call is asynchronous and you need to poll your readyState variable every few milliseconds to see when it changes. This is the reason it is working with the alert() - the alert is causing a long pause during which the AJAX response is recieved by the client. The readyState variable is checked after the alert has got a response and your code executes as needed.

However, without the alert(), your code checks for the readyState variable just **once**

One way around is to make the call **synchronous** by setting the asynchronous parameter to false in the call. This has a downside that the client will freeze until the AJAX response is received.

Another way is to keep polling the readyState variable.

Basically, you should not trust the callback function to execute itself properly - it gets stuck many times!

Comment: I'm not sure this explain the scenario in the question.  readyState 4 is the final state so I can't see how the presence of the alert affects anything.